# Receive 'illegal instruction' fault running Hyperledger Fabric "Build your first network" sample

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am attempting to run the "Build your first network" sample and receiving an "illegal instruction" fault running Hyperledger Fabric v1.0.1:

```
./byfn.sh -m generate
Generating certs and genesis block for with channel 'mychannel' and CLI timeout of '10000'
Continue (y/n)? y
proceeding ...
/tjr/bin/cryptogen

##########################################################
##### Generate certificates using cryptogen tool #########
##########################################################
org1.example.com
SIGILL: illegal instruction
PC=0x64d1af m=0

goroutine 1 [running]:
crypto/sha256.block(0xc42009e880, 0xc4200572c0, 0x40, 0x41)
    /opt/go/go1.7.linux.amd64/src/crypto/sha256/sha256block_amd64.s:733 +0x286f fp=0xc4200e2818 sp=0xc4200e25f0
crypto/sha256.(*digest).Write(0xc42009e880, 0xc4200572c0, 0x41, 0x41, 0xc4200572c0, 0x41, 0x41)
    /opt/go/go1.7.linux.amd64/src/crypto/sha256/sha256.go:119 +0x120 fp=0xc4200e2860 sp=0xc4200e2818
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bccsp/sw.(*ecdsaPrivateKey).SKI(0xc4200282c0, 0x415168, 0x8, 0x6c13c0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

h/t Gari Singh

Unfortunately, it looks like you've actually run into the following Golang issue:   https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18512 .
The good news is the issue has been fixed.  The (somewhat) bad news is that it was not fixed in Go 1.7.X (which is used to compile the binaries).

You can build the binaries yourself locally using Golang 1.8 or later.

Note that this problem will resolve itself when [FAB-5461](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5461) is merged - likely v1.1.